# Reaction sheme for Saponification with chemfig: horizontal and vertical placement

Tags: chemfig

I want to draw the formation of a fat molecule like shown in the picture below

[image: Bildung eines Fettmoleküls]

I tried with hspace/vspace and yshift:

```
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{C(-[2,0.7])(-[4,0.7])(-[0]\lewis{57,O}(-[1]H))(-[6,3]C(-[2,0.7])(-[4,0.7])(-[0]\lewis{57,O}(-[1]H))(-[6,3]C(-[2,0.7])(-[4,0.7])(-[0]\lewis{57,O}(-[1]H))(-[6,0.7])))} \+ \chemfig{\lewis{57,O}(-[4]H)(-[1]C(=[3]\lewis{24,O})(-C_{15}H_{31}))} \arrow{0}[,0] \hspace*{-4.125cm} \+ \chemfig{\lewis{57,O}(-[4]\textcolor{red}{H})(-[1]C(=[3]\lewis{24,O})(-C_{15}H_{31}))}  \chemmove[orientation/.style={rotate=0},xshift=-2cm, yshift=-2cm]{
    \draw[orientation,draw=black,opacity=.2,fill=black!30]
node[pos=.25,above,opacity=1,orientation]{\+ \chemfig{\lewis{57,O}(-[4]\textcolor{red}{H})(-[1]C(=[3]\lewis{24,O})(-C_{15}H_{31}))}} ;
}
   \schemestop
  \end{document}
```

This isn't nice.
How can I achieve a perfect alignment with chemfig?

Comment: As the question has been translated I've tided up the comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only after I had the code finished I realised that your code shows something different than the picture. But the alignment idea should work nonetheless.

As you might know `chemfig` allows to add anchor names in compounds using the `@{<name>}` syntax which can be referred to in `\chemmove` for example, but also in arrows `\arrow(@<name>--)`. The code below uses this for aligning the fatty acids `\arrow(@OH1.base east--.base west){0}[,.2]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \small
  \setatomsep{2em}
  \schemestart
    \subscheme{
      \chemfig{
        H-C(-[2]H)(
          -[6,2]C(-[4]H)(-@{OH2}OH)
          -[6,2]C(-[4]H)(-@{OH3}OH)
          -[6]H
        )
        -@{OH1}OH
      }
      \arrow(@OH1.base east--.base west){0}[,.2]
      \+ \chemname{\chemfig{C_{17}H_{33}COOH}}{Ölsäure}
      \arrow(@OH2.base east--.base west){0}[,.2]
      \+ \chemname{\chemfig{C_{3}H_{7}COOH}}{Buttersäure}
      \arrow(@OH3.base east--.base west){0}[,.2]
      \+ \chemname{\chemfig{C_{17}H_{35}COOH}}{Stearinsäure}
    }
    \arrow{<=>[Veresterung][Verseifung]}[,1.5]
    \chemfig{
      H-C(-[2]H)(
        -[6,2]C(-[4]H)(-O-C(=[2]O)-C_{3}H_{7})
        -[6,2]C(-[4]H)(-O-C(=[2]O)-C_{17}H_{35})
        -[6]H
      )
      -O-C(=[2]O)-C_{17}H_{33}
    }
  \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```