# Stacking molecules vertically

Tags: chemfig

I've been using Chemfig to try to draw the following image:
[image: Target structure]

So far, this is what I've been able to get:
[image]

I'd like to be able to stack the 3 Biodiesel molecules vertically like the original picture, but how would I edit my code?

```
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{CHOOCR''(-[2]CH_2OOCR')(-[6]CH_2OOCR''')}}{Triglyceride}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{3CH_3OH}}{Methanol}
\arrow{<=>[Catalyst]}
\chemname{\chemfig{R'COOCH_3} \+ \chemfig{R''COOCH_3} \+ \chemfig{R'''COOCH_3}}{Biodiesel}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{CHOH(-[2]CH_2OH)(-[6]CH_2OOH)}}{Glycerol}
\schemestop
```

I've taken a look at the following:
[Reaction sheme for Saponification with chemfig: horizontal and vertical placement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252811/reaction-sheme-for-saponification-with-chemfig-horizontal-and-vertical-placemen?rq=1)

[Arranging vertical reaction with "plus(+)" in chemfig scheme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318639/arranging-vertical-reaction-with-plus-in-chemfig-scheme?rq=1)

[Chemfig: how to write vertically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79758/chemfig-how-to-write-vertically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant solution, using a lot of invisible arrows but…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \chemname{\chemfig{CHOOCR''(-[2]CH_2OOCR')(-[6]CH_2OOCR''')}}{Triglyceride}
  \+
  \chemnameinit{}
  \chemname{\chemfig{3CH_3OH}}{Methanol}
  \arrow(.base east--bio.base west){<=>[Catalyst][][4pt]}
  \chemfig{R''COOCH_3}
  \arrow(.base east--.base west){0}[,0]
  \+
  \chemnameinit{}
  \chemname{\chemfig{CHOH(-[2]CH_2OH)(-[6]CH_2OOH)}}{Glycerol}
  \arrow(@bio--){0}[90,.15]
  \+
  \arrow{0}[90,.15]
  \chemfig{R'COOCH_3}
  \arrow(@bio--){0}[-90,.15]
  \+
  \arrow{0}[-90,.15]
  \chemnameinit{}
  \chemname{\chemfig{R'''COOCH_3}}{Biodiesel}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful :) The methanol name might not be aligned with the others, but I think it works better this way

Comment: @Alisa you can align it with `Triglyceride` by leaving the first `\chemnameinit{}` away but `Biodiesel` and `Glycerol` are not aligned either so I agree: no alignment of the captions seems to be the easiest option.